# Ubuntu won't connect to university internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, networkmanager

My WiFi adapter shows networks in the area, but will not allow me to connect to my university Internet.

Normally, on Windows, I connect to the Wifi by clicking connect. It shows it as connected, but nothing works. Once I type in a website, say "google.com" I am re-directed to a non-branded log in page. I type in my username and password there in the browser, and it works.

On Ubuntu, I click connect, it attempts to make the connection (shows wifi loading symbol in bar), and then a minute or so later a notification pops up saying "You are now disconnected."

Here is the result of `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog`

```
NetworkManager[900]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
NetworkManager[900]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
NetworkManager[900]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.
NetworkManager[900]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [50 120 53]
NetworkManager[900]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
NetworkManager[900]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'LSMSA'
NetworkManager[900]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
NetworkManager[900]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
NetworkManager[900]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
NetworkManager[900]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
```

I found a thread suggesting that I configure WiFi using WPA & WPA2 Enterprise and setting the authentication to PEAP, but that did not work.

Why  can't I connect to the WPA2 Enterprise access point at my university? Can any readers suggest a possible fix to allow this computer to connect to my campus encrypted WiFi network from Linux?

Comment: What authentication is your Uni using?  I would try `MS-CHAP` if it's a Windows joint...

Comment: "I found a thread suggesting to configure that WiFi using WPA & WPA2 Enterprise" well, if you don't know what is the authentication method your network is using, obviously it isn't going to work. Ask your network manager for what configuration is required,

Comment: Windows says Security Type is "No authentication (Open)" and Encryption Type is None.

Comment: Please reopen this question. This is a valid issue that affects many people (including me). But it is not clear which version of Ubuntu your laptop uses. It also helps to specify the wireless hardware on your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put a question into your Question so that it becomes clear what you're asking.

If you're wanting to determine the authentication method, here are a couple of approaches.

Boot your Windows system, connect, and then take a look to see what authentication method it has used. On Windows 8.1 right click the Network Icon (bottom right), open the Network and Sharing Center, and click on the wireless connection name (on the right-hand side). Choose [Wireless Properties] and then the Security tab.

Once you have the appropriate method you can apply it to your Ubuntu installation and try again.

On the other hand it might be easier and quicker just to ask your university's IT service-desk.

---

If you have determined that Windows declares the network to be "No authentication (open)" with encryption type "None" then that's what your Ubuntu system needs to use. There's absolutely no point trying to force the use of WPA/WPA2 Enterprise if the connection doesn't want it.

Comment: Windows says Security Type is "No authentication (Open)" and Encryption Type is None.

Comment: I went to the folder shrodi mentioned but my computer does not have the file he/she says to alter. In IraB's answer, that is.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for "***association took too long, failing activation***" came up with this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+bug/1311257

Try running `killall wpa_supplicant`

There are some simple scripts in that bug report that can automate it on resume.

Comment: I went to the folder shrodi mentioned but my computer does not have the file he/she says to alter.